# Does logstash update the .sincedb file after a log file is completely processed or during the reading process?

Tags: logstash

Does Logstash update the .sincedb file after a log file is read till the end or during the reading process ?

For example:
Let's say there is directory which is being monitored by Logstash. A file [say file1.log with max offset (file size) as 10000 ] is copied into this directory.

Does .sincedb file gets updated/created (if not already present) with the info of file1.log when the Logstash reaches offset 10000 ?

What I think is logstash should update the .sincedb file on regular basis, but what I have noticed is that it gets updated/created after a file is completely read.

Answer (score 0):

The logstash `file` input plugin will write the sincedb file on a regular basis based on the [`sincedb_write_interval`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-sincedb_write_interval) setting.

By default, the sincedb database is written every 15 seconds.

Comment: That is how logstash should work. But in the following scenario .sincedb file was being updated only when a file was completed read.
<br/>
I had put 10 files (~100MB each = ~1GB ) in the folder monitored by logstash. Logstash took 10 minutes (approx) to read each file and only then the entry of that particular file was entered in the .sincedb file.

I even set the value of sincedb_write_interval  to 30 but this had no effect.
<br/>
Logstash shows inconsistent behaviour with the .sincedb file.
<br/>
Any idea what's going on here ?